# Fourier coefficients for $f(x)=\sin(14x)+30\cos(25x)$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-series

I tried and got zero for $a_0, a_n$ and $ b_n$. I do not know if that is correct, but that just looks weird. However, the function looks weird too. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All coefficients are zero except $a_{25}$ and $b_{14}$.

Comment: At one point I get in this: $\int_0^\pi 30 \cos (nx) \cos(25x)dx$
If I apply orthogonality relations, I get your result, but let's say I didn't notice that and continued. Through addition theorems I would get: $\int_0^\pi \cos(nx+25x) + \cos (nx-25x) dx$
After integrating I would get somewhere $1_(n-25)$, so that means I can't even put 25 in the equation. What is wrong with my thinking?

Comment: And when $n=25$ that integral is?

Comment: Sorry, meant to write 1/(n-25).

Comment: That would mean that for $n=25$ the computation cannot be done like this.